# Pyqt5, AttributeError: module 'x_ui' has no attribute 'Ui_x'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Hello I have a QTDesigner UI file HelloWorld.ui which I am trying to import into a project and execute.

The Project includes HelloWorld.ui file which has been converted into HelloWorld_ui.py using Pyuic5.

The following is the code of app.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import sys
import HelloWorld_ui



class HelloWorld(QDialog, HelloWorld_ui.Ui_HelloWorld):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
helloworld = HelloWorld()
helloworld.show()
app.exec_()
```

The following is the error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rrpolak/Downloads/Pyt/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    class HelloWorld(QDialog, HelloWorld_ui.Ui_HelloWorld):
AttributeError: module 'HelloWorld_ui' has no attribute 'Ui_HelloWorld'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am trying to understand what is the correct way to call these files in the python program. Any help is appreciated.

The project file is at https://drive.google.com/open?id=18tjLPiCZxTbKaiZShtgu90KyXcFukr6V

I am using PyQt5/Python3.6/Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the file HelloWorld_ui.py you will notice that there is no class called Ui_HelloWorld, but the class Ui_Dialog:

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
```

so you must use that class:

```
class HelloWorld(QDialog, HelloWorld_ui.Ui_Dialog):
```

The name is generated by the name you give to QDialog:

[image]

If you want to use `HelloWorld` you must change it:

[image]

convert the .ui to .py again and execute it again obtaining the following:

[image]